# How to split a dataframe column into more columns, conditional to another column value?

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, tuples

I am stuck because I can not split a dataframe column into more columns, conditional to another column value. I have a pandas dataframe which I generated straight from a '.csv' file with more than 100K rows.

Excerpt1:

[image]

I want to split column `dca` by ',' (comma) into more columns. The number of splits will be constrained by the values in `n_mppts`.

Edited on 2023-04-12:

I could succesfully perform the split column operation in the dataframe generated from this .csv file with the following code (thanks to @Abdulmajeed's solution):

```
def split_dca(row):
    values = row['dca'].split(',') if row['dca'] else []
    values += [float('NaN')] * (row['n_mppts'] - len(values))
    values = values[:row['n_mppts']]
    return pd.Series(values)

df_dca_dcv.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 418643 entries, 0 to 418642
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------       --------------   ----- 
 0   pipe_id      418643 non-null  int64 
 1   date         418643 non-null  object
 2   inverter_id  418643 non-null  object
 3   n_mppts      418643 non-null  int64 
 4   dca          418538 non-null  object
 5   dcv          418538 non-null  object
dtypes: int64(2), object(4)
memory usage: 19.2+ MB

df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].str.replace('{', '')
df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].str.replace('}', '')
df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].astype(str)
```

Excerpt2:

[image]

```
mppts_dca = df_dca_dcv.apply(split_dca, axis=1)
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_0'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[0], errors='coerce')
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_1'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[1], errors='coerce')
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_2'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[2], errors='coerce')
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_3'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[3], errors='coerce')
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_4'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[4], errors='coerce')
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_5'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[5], errors='coerce')
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_6'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[6], errors='coerce')
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_7'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[7], errors='coerce')
mppts_dca['dca_mppt_8'] = pd.to_numeric(mppts_dca[8], errors='coerce')
df_dca_dcv = pd.concat([df_dca_dcv, mppts_dca], axis=1)
```

Excerpt3:

[image]

However, I am facing a problem when I generate the dataframe from a pandas sql query specifying `inverter_id`=a2 and therefore the current solution wont succeed (the issue also persists with other `inverter_id` values):

```
df_dca_dcv = pd.read_sql_query("select pipe_id,created_at as date,inverter_id,n_mppts,dca,dcv from inverters where inverter_id = 'a2' order by pipe_id, inverter_id, date;", con=con) # connected to a postgreSQL db
df_dca_dcv.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 16507 entries, 0 to 16506
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------       --------------  -----         
 0   pipe_id      16507 non-null  object        
 1   date         16507 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 2   inverter_id  16507 non-null  object        
 3   n_mppts      16507 non-null  int64         
 4   dca          16428 non-null  object        
 5   dcv          16428 non-null  object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 773.9+ KB
```

Column `dca` Dtype is still object, but now it has values between "[ ]" instead of "{ }" (unlike in Excerpt 1), and when I perform this:

```
df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].str.replace('[', '')
df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].str.replace(']', '')
df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].astype(str)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 2
      1 df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].str.replace("[", "")
----> 2 df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].str.replace("]", "")

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py:182, in CachedAccessor.__get__(self, obj, cls)
    179 if obj is None:
    180     # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    181     return self._accessor
--> 182 accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    183 # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    184 # https://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html
    185 # We need to use object.__setattr__ because we overwrite __setattr__ on
    186 # NDFrame
    187 object.__setattr__(obj, self._name, accessor_obj)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py:177, in StringMethods.__init__(self, data)
    174 def __init__(self, data):
    175     from pandas.core.arrays.string_ import StringDtype
--> 177     self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
    178     self._is_categorical = is_categorical_dtype(data.dtype)
    179     self._is_string = isinstance(data.dtype, StringDtype)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py:231, in StringMethods._validate(data)
    228 inferred_dtype = lib.infer_dtype(values, skipna=True)
    230 if inferred_dtype not in allowed_types:
--> 231     raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
    232 return inferred_dtype

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I antecipated the ".astype(str)" operation, and then performed the ".str.replace(...)" operations. However, when I look at the dataframe now

Excerpt4:

[image]

column `dca` values are not in the same format as they are in Excerpt2 (e.g. "Decimal('2.2'),Decimal('2.2')..."). When I go ahead and execute

```
mppts_dca = df_dca_dcv.apply(split_dca, axis=1)
df_dca_dcv = pd.concat([df_dca_dcv, mppts_dca], axis=1)
df_dca_dcv['date'] = df_dca_dcv['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df_dca_dcv['dca_mppt_0'] = pd.to_numeric(df_dca_dcv[0], errors='coerce')
df_dca_dcv['dca_mppt_1'] = pd.to_numeric(df_dca_dcv[1], errors='coerce')
```

the `dca` values are not passed to the newly splited columns, which (I suppose) is because "pd.to_numeric(" can't read "Decimal(...)":

Excerpt5:

[image]

I've tried all the following methods to convert `dca` column to string:

```
METHOD1: df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].map(str) #produced same output format as before
METHOD2: df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].apply(str) #produced same output format as before
METHOD3: df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].astype(str) #generated the following error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].values.astype(str)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

METHOD4: df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].values.astype(str) #generated same error as METHOD3

METHOD5: df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].applymap(str)  #generated the following error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].applymap(str)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

METHOD6:
def convert_float_string(row):
    float_list = row['dca']
    if len(float_list) > 0:
        string_list = ["%.2f" % i for i in float_list]
    else:
        string_list = float('NaN')
    return string_list
df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv.apply(lambda row: convert_float_string(row), axis=1) #generated the following error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv.apply(lambda row: convert_float_string(row), axis=1)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8839, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   8828 from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply
   8830 op = frame_apply(
   8831     self,
   8832     func=func,
   (...)
   8837     kwargs=kwargs,
   8838 )
-> 8839 return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:727, in FrameApply.apply(self)
    724 elif self.raw:
    725     return self.apply_raw()
--> 727 return self.apply_standard()
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:851, in FrameApply.apply_standard(self)
    850 def apply_standard(self):
--> 851     results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    853     # wrap results
    854     return self.wrap_results(results, res_index)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:867, in FrameApply.apply_series_generator(self)
    864 with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
    865     for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    866         # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 867         results[i] = self.f(v)
    868         if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    869             # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because
    870             #  series_generator will swap out the underlying data
    871             results[i] = results[i].copy(deep=False)
Cell In[8], line 1, in <lambda>(row)
----> 1 df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv.apply(lambda row: convert_float_string(row), axis=1)
Cell In[6], line 3, in convert_float_string(row)
      1 def convert_float_string(row):
      2     float_list = row['dca']
----> 3     if len(float_list) > 0:
      4         string_list = ["%.2f" % i for i in float_list]
      5     else:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

...and if I simply skip converting `dca` to string and use

```
df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].replace("[", "")
df_dca_dcv['dca'] = df_dca_dcv['dca'].replace("]", "")
```

the replacement does not take place.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix that issue.

Comment: After `pd.read_sql_query(...)` can you provide the exact output of `print(df_dca_dcv.head(5).to_dict())`, please?

Comment: Hi @Corralien, I've added the output you requested by the end of the main question as there isn't space to post it in the comments.

Comment: All `dca` and `dcv` are always a length of 11 elements?

Comment: @Corralien, no they are not. They can have 0 to 11 elements and the split operation should filter only the 'n' first elements from left to right, where 'n' = row['n_mppts']. Any ones beyond the 'n'th element should have value=float('NaN').

Comment: Two more question: when you have NaN in `dca` column, what is the value of `n_mppts`? Try: `df.loc[df['dca'].isna(), ['n_mppts', 'dca']]`. Are you sure the value of `n_mppts` is always lower than the length of `dca` array?

Comment: For `inverter_id`='a2', `df_dca_dcv.loc[df_dca_dcv['dca'].isna(), ['n_mppts', 'dca']]` outputs 4 rows with `n_mppts`=2 and `dca`='None'. This is because sometimes the datalogger wont send any data, so `dca` gets value 'None'. I am sure there are other cases like that for other `inverter_id`s. In those cases where `dca`='None', any column generated from the split operation should have value `float('NaN')`. Whenever the `dca` is not 'None', its length is >= `n_mppts`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253261/discussion-between-nigelblainey-and-corralien).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> They can have 0 to 11 elements and the split operation should filter only the 'n' first elements from left to right, where 'n' = row['n_mppts']

Since `dca` has variable length, you can use this code:

```
# Part 0: fix special cases
mask = df['dca'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'dca'] = df.loc[mask, 'dca'].apply(lambda x: [])
lens = df['dca'].str.len().values  # get the length of each array
n_mppts = df['n_mppts'].mask(df['n_mppts'].gt(lens), lens)

# Part 1: pad each array to be stacked
nrows, ncols = len(df), int(lens.max())
dca = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))  # create a 0s target array
mask = lens[:, None] > np.arange(ncols)
dca[mask] = np.concatenate(df['dca']).astype(float)  # copy data

# Part 2: keep values according n_mppts
mask = n_mppts.values[:, None] <= np.arange(ncols)
dca[mask] = np.nan
dca_df = pd.DataFrame(dca).add_prefix('dca_mppt_')
dca_df
```

Output:

```
   dca_mppt_0  dca_mppt_1  dca_mppt_2  dca_mppt_3  dca_mppt_4  dca_mppt_5  dca_mppt_6  dca_mppt_7  dca_mppt_8  dca_mppt_9  dca_mppt_10
0         2.3         2.3         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
1         2.6         2.6         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
2         2.9         2.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
3         6.0         5.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
4         3.9         3.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
```

---

What you receive from `read_sql_query` is a list of [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects) instances.

It seems `dca` and `dcv` are a length of 11 items. You can use numpy to get your expected output in vectorized way:

```
dca = np.vstack(df['dca']).astype(float)
mask = df['n_mppts'].values[:, None] <= np.arange(12)
dca[mask] = np.nan
dca_df = pd.DataFrame(dca).add_prefix('dca_mppt_')
```

Output:

```
>>> dca_df
   dca_mppt_0  dca_mppt_1  dca_mppt_2  dca_mppt_3  dca_mppt_4  dca_mppt_5  dca_mppt_6  dca_mppt_7  dca_mppt_8  dca_mppt_9  dca_mppt_10
0         2.3         2.3         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
1         2.6         2.6         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
2         2.9         2.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
3         6.0         5.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
4         3.9         3.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
```

Comment: I got a ValueError: "ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 11 and the array at index 63 has size 1"

Comment: It's not a big deal to handle variable array length. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: The solution is effective and solved the problem. Other users should be aware that during the implementation of 'Part 0', some `n_mppts` values may change, so if you need to summarize on that variable you should concatenate `dca_df` to a new `df`, and only then summarize it. Thank you @Corralien!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.
But you can use custom function with apply. Example below:

Hope it helps

```
def split_dca(row):
    values = row['dca'].split(',') if row['dca'] else []
    
    values += [float('NaN')] * (row['n_mppts'] - len(values))
    
    values = values[:row['n_mppts']]
    
    return pd.Series(values)

split_columns = df.apply(split_dca, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Abdulmajeed. After replacing "{" and "}" with "", and using ".astype(str)" on dca column, this function solved the issue with the .csv dataset column split, which is the main concern in my question! Would it be possible for you to provide some guidance on a secondary issue related to this split operation? When I generate the dataframe (not from a .csv file but) from a pandas sql query using "pd.read_sql_query(...)", and do the same as before, I get an error which I described in detail when I edited the main question.